# Global coordinates of object within a rotated group in fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I have a rotated fabric.js group that contains some objects. I want to get the absolute coordinates of those objects relative to the canvas.

I used object.calcTransformMatrix(), but what it gives me back are the translations not the actual position.

How to go from that matrix to get the actual position?